# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio - Edit Rows with Where clause

Tags: editing, sql-server-2008, sql-management-studio

There is an option to edit rows in a grid - first 200 by default.
In `Tools -> Options -> Sql Server Object Explorer`, you can set the value for "Edit Top N rows".

I have a table with 200000 rows. What I need to do is edit some of those elements that are almost at the end of the table. I can't set this to "Edit Top 200000 rows" because it will be just too much. However, what I'd like to do is to constraint what is shown in the edit grid - if possible by the Where clause.

For example "Edit Top 500 rows, where ID > 16000". This would be some few hundreds rows so it's ok.

Is this possible in any way, or do I have to write SQL code to update the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found out the answer to this.

If I right-click on the grid header, I can select `Pane -> SQL`. This shows the SQL statement used to fill the grid. I can add `Where` constraints there.

It's very easy solution, but I somehow missed that pane.

Comment: There is also the same button on the toolbar.